# vaadin import necessary for Page.getCurrent()

Tags: java, import, vaadin

I would like to know what's the import necessary for `Page.getCurrent()` in vaadin framework, a google search leads me to `com.vaadin.server` package, but eclipse notifies me that `import com.vaadin.server` cannot be resolved, also tried `com.vaadin.server.*` and `import com.vaadin.server.Page;` but was unable to resolve it. I'm using vaadin 6.8

here is the class I'm trying to run

```
package com.example.juju;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window.Notification;

public class JujuApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void init() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("Myproject");

        // Notification with default settings for a warning
        Notification notif = new Notification("Warning",
                                              "<br/>Area of reindeer husbandry",
                                              Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);

        // Customize it 
        notif.setDelayMsec(20000);
        notif.setPosition(Notification.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        notif.setStyleName("mystyle");

        // Show it in the page
        notif.show(Page.getCurrent());

        setMainWindow(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using the step by step for newbies guide provided in the book of vaadin [link](https://vaadin.com/book), not maven. thanks

Comment: In which part of the book is the `Page.getCurrent()` method mentioned?

Comment: your last comment given me a hint that it's probably a compatibility issue, Page.getCurrent() is mentioned in vaadin 7 book, and I was thinking I was reading vaading 6 book, buceause I'm having vaading 6 installed on my system, but still not sure whether it's related to version compatibility. anyways here is where Page.getCurrent() is mentioned https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.notifications.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Page.getCurrent()
```

is a supported in vaadin 7 according to vaadin forum and not vaadin 6.x